# How to refer the team persons in the conversation?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request

Situation is this, there is team of 3 persons including. I want to inform the team's action to someone outside this team.

Can I use the phrase "we three decided to take this action"? here my doubt is, when I use "We" is that include the person to whom I informing?

what is the alternate phrase to express?

Comment: Please not that the word **persons** is used in legal language, the plural form is **people**.

Comment: *We* is ambiguous. It might include the person spoken to or it might not. It has to be known from context, or the speaker needs to add some additional phrase to make it clear whether the other person is included or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking to somebody outside the team, and you use **we**, they won't think of themselves as part of the team you are in, because they know that they won't play a match with you (supposed that it is so).

If you want to avoid issuing an ambiguous phrase, you can say something like:

> We, I mean me and two other people, decided to take an action.
>
> We three in the team decided to take an action.

Comment: Yes, this exactly.  It can also change with context, for example you can use intonation or gesture to indicate the people in the team, not the people hearing the conversation.  But by default most English speakers will understand what you *mean*, even if the words themselves are ambiguous.